# I want to inprove JOIN SQL performance

Tags: sql, oracle

below codes are a query that select the latest data of each CID. but query are  slow (about 4sec).

#### TABLE INFO

CID, GATH_DTM(datatype: date) are PK.

DATA_STAT_CODE is a flag.

#### INDEX : COLUMNS

- PK_020 : CID, GATH_DTM
- IDX_020_STAT_CODE : DATA_STAT_CODE, CID, GATH_DTM
- TABLE_INDEX : GATH_DTM
- ACCUM_IDX : ACCUM_QTY

#### OPTIMIZER PLAN RESULT

- HASH GROUP BY : INDEX RANGE SCAN
- NESTED LOOP : INDEX RANGE SCAN

#### SELECT RESULT

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_020; and SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_020 WHERE DATA_STAT_CODE = 28001;
```

> 3591336

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_020; and SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_020;
```

> 4179537

### SQL

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TB_020 E, 
       (SELECT /*+ INDEX(TB_020 IDX_020_STAT_CODE)*/ 
              CID, 
              MAX(GATH_DTM) GATH_DTM 
         FROM TB_020 
        WHERE DATA_STAT_CODE=28001 
    GROUP BY CID 
       ) J 
 WHERE E.GATH_DTM=J.GATH_DTM 
   AND E.CID =J.CID
```

I want to improve a performance.

Comment: You have multiple queries.  Which do you want to improve the performance on?

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh, I want to SQL1(now SQL, remove SQL2)

Comment: Go for ANSI JOIN syntax. INNER JOIN . You are using old JOIN syntax

Comment: @VenkataramanR yes, I already tried it. but performance still same.

Comment: @sw.jeong, I am not telling from performance point of view for ANSI JOIN syntaxt. More in terms of code maintainability and obsoleteness of code and adhering to standard.

Comment: @VenkataramanR Ok, thanks. I try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to avoid index hint. ORACLE knows better using cost based optimizer. Moreover, as data grows, you current index hint might be out of date. You are already having sufficient indexes, I feel. Just try the below and see whether your query performs better.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TB_020 AS E
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
              CID, 
              MAX(GATH_DTM) GATH_DTM 
         FROM TB_020 
        WHERE DATA_STAT_CODE=28001 
    GROUP BY CID 
       ) AS J 
 ON E.GATH_DTM=J.GATH_DTM 
   AND E.CID =J.CID
```

Comment: oh, Its more faster than old query.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
   select *     
     from tb_020 e    
    where E.GATH_DTM in (SELECT MAX(GATH_DTM) GATH_DTM 
                           FROM TB_020 j
                          WHERE DATA_STAT_CODE = 28001 
                            AND j.CID = e.cid);
```

Comment: running time is drecread from 4sec to 2sec. but I want to decrease more..

Comment: try this too.. select * from (       
    SELECT e.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.CID ORDER BY e.GATH_DTM desc) seq_no
      FROM tb_020 e where e.DATA_STAT_CODE = 28001 
     )
where seq_no = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You may use  `row_number()`

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY GATH_DTM DESC ) as rn
         FROM TB_020 t
        WHERE DATA_STAT_CODE=28001 
) WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: this query is slower more than old one.

Comment: @sw.jeong : As the other answer mentions, also try this query without those hints.